# Taking regard of uncertainty & error bars in a graph

Tags: error-analysis

Is there any way that I can take regards of horizontal error bars to get uncertainties in the slope and the y-intercept?

I'm a high school student and the only method I learned in physics class is trying to plot a maximum gradient curve and a minimum gradient curve, which is impossible (I think) in this case as the average line (automatically plotted by the Excel) does not go through all error bars in the graph.

To briefly explain the graph, it is about linear radius variation vs angular diameter variation of a Cepheid variable, one type of pulsating stars in the space. The y-intercept represents the average radius of the star and the gradient can be used to calculate the distance to the star.

[image]

Comment: There is.  The mathematics in on this page on the [least squares fit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html).  It the standard error for the intercept and slope ( $a$ and $b$ respectively on that page ) which are shown at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @StephenG That should be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the meaning of your error bars. If they represent [standard errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) and indeed a straight line is the correct physical description of your correlation, then the "best-fitting" line should only go through approximately 2/3 of the error bars.

There are a number of correct-ish ways to do what you want to do. The easiest, in my opinion is to perform a mininimum chi-squared fit (or a "*weighted* least squares fit"). A standard "least squares fit" is inappropriate for [heteroscedastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) data (where the uncertainties on each point are different).

To do this, you should plot your graph, so that the y-axis has the uncertainty, whereas the x-axis uncertainties are negligible. You then calculate the [reduced chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic) statistic for any trial straight line and use an iterative method to calculate the best-fitting parameters and their uncertainties. This is a very standard approach that can be found in many textbooks. As far as implementations go, you can use [python (scipy)](https://python4mpia.github.io/fitting_data/least-squares-fitting.html) or [gnuplot](http://theochem.ki.ku.dk/on_line_docs/gnuplot/gnuplot_21.html).

Comment: Do you mean the 'best-fitting' line is not a good description of my data?  Also, can I conduct the chi-squared fit or any similar fitting which is appropriate for this problem in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment request, I've written my comment as an answer.

The mathematics on this page on the [least squares fit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) is what you need.

The standard error for the intercept and slope ($a$ and $b$ respectively on that page) are shown at the bottom of the page.

Comment: But this isn't a "least squares" fitting problem, because the individual data points have differing uncertainties. A least squares fit would give a different answer to one which minimised chi-squared or adopted a Bayesian approach.